# Can a model belong_to more than one model?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nested, associations

```
class Comment < ActiveRecord::Base  
  belongs_to :post  
  belongs_to :user  
end
```

So with the above association can I fetch both user and post details from a given comment object?.
like

```
@comment.post.post_title and  
@comment.user.user_name.
```

Also please note that I have used comment as a nested resource of post.

```
resources :posts do  
   resources :comments  
end
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes you can, and you don't need to specify the foreign key or class name to do so.  Saying `belongs_to :user` means rails will look for a user_id integer field in the comments table, and expect an ActiveRecord class named User to exist.

Add as many as you like, they don't interfere with each other.

Comment: Is this new as of Rails 3? I certainly had to specify a foreign key to do this in Rails 2.3.2, and I upgraded to Rails 3 so recently that I haven't had the chance to try this.

Comment: No, this isn't new, it goes back as far as 1.2 (the earliest version I used).  A model can have any number of associations (has_many, belongs_to, etc) and they don't affect each other.  The only time you need to specify class_name and foreign_key is when they're different from what rails would expect.

Comment: Well that's news to me, since I know I tried this and it didn't work until I added code similar to the example that I cited. Maybe it was a subclassing/STI issue, I don't remember.

Comment: There were a lot of things when I started rails that didn't work like I thought, so I'd grind away until I found something that did work, and move on.  Later I'd come back to find my solution was overkill :)  This might be one of those cases. I think it's a bigger possibility in frameworks like this where a lot of "magic" happens behind the scenes.